# What is a lock in Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

In the Azure Container Registry blade in the Azure portal, there is a "Lock" section on the left hand side and I can't find it anywhere in the [ACR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/).

What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a general Azure (not specific to ACR) feature to prevent accidental deletion (or modification) of a resource. You can create a lock that would prevent users from deleting or modifying the resource while the lock is there (even if they have the permissions to delete\modify the resource).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources